# Why Am I getting COMException while trying to connect ServerManager from Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I want to retrieve the list of sites from remote IIS:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("myserver");
```

I am getting a COMException

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine {ip} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Any tips?

Please, I don't want other approach how to get the information without using Microsoft.Web.Administration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suspicious then I found this [Link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1162202.aspx/1) which means I can't use with IIS 6 which is the case... What I want to use using Microsoft.Web.Administration only works for IIS 7